# Atari ST image viewer with unusual zoom

Tags: graphics, programming, identify-this-software, atari-st

I'm looking for info on an Atari ST (16-color) full-screen image viewer that I once used.  When zooming in the edges between colors were smoothly curved (instead of e.g. no smoothing or interpolation and dithering).  As I recall the effect was similar to Bézier curves and was done in real-time (or close to real-time).  I've replicated a similar effect in my own code (see images below) but my algorithm relies on modern hardware (fast CPU, multiprocessing, floating point math).  I would very much like to know how this was done on an 8 MHz 68000.  So my questions are:

1. Does anyone know which program this was? 
   (I suspect it was written in the UK but I'm not positive.)
2. Can it be downloaded anywhere?
3. Is the algorithm described anywhere?
4. Is the source code available?

Here's the output of my algorithm (click to embiggen):

| Original | Zoomed |
| --- | --- |
| [image: Original image] | [image: Zoomed image] |

Each square on the left-hand image is a single pixel on the original image. 
Images shown are a cropped detail of the actual images.

Comment: Is the source code of *your* program available?

Comment: @texdr.aft Not currently.  I could describe the algorithm if you're interested.

Comment: Upvote for use of embiggen.